# Meaning of 来 after and before certain verbs

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

What's the purpose of 来 in the following sentences?

1. 他给我买什么**来**了？
2. 我汉字写得太慢。你**来**写吧。
3. 我**来**买票.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"来" has multiple meanings and uses. https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%9D%A5

- **买来**, **买**什么**来** - "bought-in", "bought what in".
  他给我**买**什么**来**了？ What has he bought in for me?
- 用在另一动词前，表示要做某件事 (**Do**, or willing/eager to do, something)。

  2. 我汉字写得太慢。你**来写**吧。- My writing is too slow, You **do** the writing instead.
  3. 我**来买**票. - I **do** the ticket purchasing. (Let me purchase the ticket).

Answer (score 2):

1. I believe its a case of its original meaning: to come (from another place t o where the speaker is). In this case "his" buying it for me got me it from another place to where I am.

2 & 3. Used before a verb to express volition.

讓我來做吧。 / 让我来做吧。  ―  Ràng wǒ lái zuò ba.  ―  Let me do it. ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BE%86#Chinese))

Answer (score 0):

去 and 来 are both often used in Chinese to indicate the direction of motion.

你过来： you pass from: come here
我过去： I pass to: I'm coming

Older English had **hence** = 去 = to and **hither** = 来  = from, also **whence** and **whither**, but these are hardly used nowadays.

Hie thee **hence** = go you from: go away
come **hither** = come from: come here

German **hin** means: direction to or towards something: 去
German **her** (say the same as English hair) means: direction away, from where you are：来

Maybe, in your language, you have similar words to indicate direction.

In translation, these directional forms of 来 and 去 often get lost.

他给我买什么来了？ 买来 = buy from
you for me buy what from le
Was hast du mir gekauft?
What did you buy for me?

多少钱能买来快乐？买来 = buy from
much little money can buy from happiness?
Für wieviel Geld ist Glück zu haben?
How much money buys happiness？

我汉字写得太慢。你来写吧。来写 = come (to) write
I Chinese characters write de very slow. you come write ok
Ich bin sehr langsam in Chinesisch schreiben. Schreib du doch.
I'm pretty slow at writing Chinese. You write it.

我坐**下来**写信求情。下来 = down from
I sit down from write letter ask favour
Ich saß mich hin um einen Brief zu schreiben, eine Bitte um einen Gefallen.
I sat down to write a letter asking for a favour.

我来买票. 来买 = come (to) buy
I come buy ticket
Ich bin gekommen um eine Fahrkarte/Eintrittskarte zukaufen.
I've come to buy a ticket.

你来干什么？来干 = come (to) do
you come do what
Was willst du?
What do you want?

我来买饮料。来买 = come (to) buy
I come buy drinks
I möchte Getränke kaufen.
I've come to buy some drinks.

In fact, the distinction between **come** and **from** is unclear and artificial, because, any time you **come**, you **from**, so to speak. You can't **come** to somewhere without moving **from** somewhere else.